# Passing data into a c-string within a struct in a .h file from .cpp file

Tags: c++, input, struct, header-files, cstring

I have a struct defined in a .h file. I must pass in info from the user from the .cpp file into a c-string within the struct. I'm not sure how. Any suggestions? 
Code from employ.h file:

```
#ifndef EMPLOY_H_
#define EMPLOY_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct employ
{
    const int nameLen = 30; //Length of name strings
    const int ssnLen = 11;  //Length of ssn string
    char firstName[nameLen];        //Employee first name
    char lastName[nameLen];     //Employee last name
    char midInit;           //Employee middle initial
    char SSN[ssnLen];           //Employee Social Security Number
    int hireDay,            //Day hired
    hireMonth,          //Month hired
    hireYear;           //Year hired
    double annSalary;       //Annual salary of employee
    long empNumber;         //Employee number
};
```

Code from .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include "employ.h"

using namespace std;

void sort(employee*dbaseArray, int numEmps);
void printEmps(employee*dbaseArray, int numEmps);
void printOne(employee person);

int main()
{
    int numEmps;
    int count = 1;
    cout << "How many employees are in the company? ";
    cin >> numEmps;
    if (numEmps < 1)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, that is an invalid number. Try Again: ";
        cin >> numEmps;
    }
    while (count <= numEmps)
    {
            cout << "What is employee's first name? ";
        cin.getline(firstName, nameLen);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you just using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: Where are you trying to put data into an `employ`? I don't see you instantiate `employ` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the `employ` struct in the main. Can you make changes to the `employ` structure?

If you can make changes you could change the `char` arrays you have in thre for `std::string`.

The `sort` algorithm you are using could also probably be changed for something already done in `std::algorithm`.

Beware of `using namespace std;`, in fact, don't use it in your header file.

```
int main()
{
    int numEmps;
    int count = 1;
    employ test; // This is your instance
    cout << "How many employees are in the company? ";
    cin >> numEmps;
    if (numEmps < 1)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, that is an invalid number. Try Again: ";
        cin >> numEmps;
    }
    while (count <= numEmps)
    {
        cout << "What is employee's first name? ";
        cin.getline(firstName, nameLen);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Also, if you use `std::string` you'll be needing `std::stringstream` and `std::getline`, which would save you some headaches in the future regarding `\n`.

For example you are using:

```
cout << "How many employees are in the company? ";
cin >> numEmps;
if (numEmps < 1)
{
    cout << "Sorry, that is an invalid number. Try Again: ";
    cin >> numEmps;
}
```

Which would be:

```
   std::string input; 
   while (true) {
     std::cout << "How many employees are in the company? " << std::endl;
     std::getline(cin, input);
     std::stringstream myStream(input);
     if (myStream >> numEmps)
     {
       break;
     } else
     {
       std::cout << "Sorry, that is an invalid number." << std::endl;
     }
   }
```

For your second question you'll be needing a dynamic array, I suggest `std::vector<employ>`, you would use it like this.

```
int main()
{
    int numEmps;
    int count = 1;
    cout << "How many employees are in the company? ";
    cin >> numEmps;
    if (numEmps < 1)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, that is an invalid number. Try Again: ";
        cin >> numEmps;
    }
    std::vector<employ> employees;
    employees.resize(numEmps);
    std::vector<employ>::iterator it;
    for(it = employees.begin(); it != employees.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::string name;
        cout << "What is employee's first name? ";
        std::getline(cin, name);
        name.copy(it->firstname, (it->nameLen)-1);
        it->firstname[it->nameLen] = '\0'; // Told you to change the struct char arrays for strings
    }
    return 0;
 }
```